# POSGAR CRS With Reversed X and Y coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

I've been working in the Argentine CRS of POSGAR (Specifically POSGAR 94/Argentina 2 EPSG:22182) frequently and have noticed on a number of occasions that coordinates are provided to me with the X coordinate being the north-south direction and the Y coordinate being the east-west direction.  I was told this was due to the specification of POSGAR being with X-Y defined this way, but using ArcMap, QGIS, etc. all of the standard software seem to interpret X as East-West and Y as North-South.

Obviously, I can just reverse the coordinates and it's not a big deal, but I was curious about the heritage of this system. I was wondering if anyone could point me to any references or knew if POSGAR was originally defined with the X and Y reversed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/posgar-94-argentina-2/html/) and [OGC](http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/22182) it is shown as a NE-axis projection, while [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/22182) says its EN-axis.

So to check a definitive source goto the [EPSG](http://www.epsg-registry.org/) themselves and it says NE.

[image]

Comment: Direct link to WKT report http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::22182

Comment: I never managed to get a link before, well done!